# How to specify a cipher in SSLStream

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ssl

I have a small client application that I want to use SSL with. I can create the stream, however, I'm being told that I HAVE to use the "AES256-SHA256" cipher.

I'm just getting my feet wet with SSL/TSL so I'm not entire sure how to specify this, if I even need to at all.

I've looked around but couldn't find anything helpful (or I couldn't make sense of it). Any help is appreciated :)

Below code is how I'm creating the SSLStream:

```
                    if (useSSL)
                    {
                        var myStream = new NetworkStream(Socket);
                        sslStream = new SslStream(myStream);
                    }
```

Comment: This should help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.authentication.cipheralgorithmtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I saw that too, but I can't make sense of it. 
The example shows how to get the read only property value of CipherAlgorithm but not anything regarding setting the CipherAlgorithmType

Comment: The way I understand it, both sides need to support the algorithm so once you make the connection, the client should set itself to the algorithm requested by the endpoint, if supported. Have you tried running it? What happens when you connect?

Comment: @Juan That was my assumption also, since there is no Set functionality. 
I haven't seen the server end myself unfortunately so I don't have much to go off of. All I know is that the server is only going to support that one specific cipher. If I don't need to set it on the client, then good for me :)

Comment: I think you should be fine. That's why we test though. At some point you will have to issue a test request. You will find out then... :-)